# Send Notification on Iphone and Android with real time

Tags: asp.net, push-notification

I am using sql server 2008 and Asp.net C#.now i want to push notification to Android and iPhone through email or SMS...how can i accomplish it.I searched it but found different methods for iPhone and android.is there any way to send notification to android and iPhone app simultaneously using same code? please provide help and also code example if u can.
Many thnks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of email or sms you can use webservice. I have also work on iOS application and for database communication we use web service that talks with application and save data and fetch data.

you just simply add web service path to your iOS application as web service will return xml as a result and iOS application can read that details and work accordingly.

Thank you.